# How do I seed Spring-Security with Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-security, spring-data, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT project that is using Spring-Security spring-security-web:4.0.0.M1.   I would like to seed the database tables in my H2 tables, but I get exceptions on startup (both with production and integration test code).

Here is my relevant schema.sql file contents:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
  username VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  password VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(500) NOT NULL,
  enabled  BOOLEAN                 NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Authorities (
  username  VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,
  authority VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_authorities_users FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ix_auth_username ON authorities (username, authority);

INSERT INTO users(username,password,enabled) VALUES ('admin','$2a$10$GVPAMYRozI08Mcll5too6.Q4M2jTO0iJVoiaVDv9pMxRqTpxNj9vO', TRUE);
INSERT INTO Authorities (username, authority) VALUES ('admin', 'ADMIN');

INSERT INTO users(username,password,enabled) VALUES ('user','$2a$10$GVPAMYRozI08Mcll5too6.Q4M2jTO0iJVoiaVDv9pMxRqTpxNj9vO', TRUE);
INSERT INTO Authorities (username, authority) VALUES ('user', 'USER');
```

I have the following in my application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

When I startup or run my tests I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource URL [file:/Users/David/projects/cnet/OFAC/out/test/OFAC/data.sql]: INSERT INTO users (username, password, enabled) VALUES ('admin', '$2a$10$GVPAMYRozI08Mcll5too6.Q4M2jTO0iJVoiaVDv9pMxRqTpxNj9vO', TRUE); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_4 ON PUBLIC.USERS(USERNAME)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO users (username, password, enabled) VALUES ('admin', '$2a$10$GVPAMYRozI08Mcll5too6.Q4M2jTO0iJVoiaVDv9pMxRqTpxNj9vO', TRUE) [23505-172]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:474)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runDataScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializer.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializer.java:46)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runSchemaScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.initialize(DataSourceInitializer.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
```

What is the best way to seed the security database tables with these user accounts?  I tried with code, but I was unable to get the loaders to work in the correct order.

**UPDATE**:
When I step thru ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate, I see that I have two instances of schema.sql being used.  They are :

```
file:.../out/test/OFAC/schema.sql
file:.../out/production/OFAC/schema.sql
```

I also have:

```
file:.../out/test/OFAC/data.sql
file:.../out/production/OFAC/data.sql
```

No harm with duplicate schema.sql there apparently.  But then in ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript() I see that both data.sql files are being invoked as well.  So, i don't see why both test and production sql files are being executed.

Comment: It looks like your build tool is creating duplicate classpaths? I guess you need to dial that back a bit and try a really simple build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are inserting a record without providing a primary key.

Also (once you solve that problem), you will face another: you can use `schema.sql` *or* `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` but not both. If you want you can use `data.sql` for the DML (inserts) in addition to `create-drop`, and then you can let Hibernate create the tables, and set up the auto-generation of primary keys (if that's what you wanted).

BTW: Boot 1.1.1.RELEASE is in Maven Central so please use that.

Comment: Dave, thank you for the feedback. I am pretty sure I have the primary key defined for my H2 table, unless that syntax is wrong.  Since I am only inserting the one unique record, I don't see why this fails.  I removed the schema.sql and let Hibernate take care of the generation, and put the insert statement into my data.sql.  That seems logical.  However, when I remove the schema.sql and use the "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop" I get table not found exceptions.

Comment: And are you using Boot 1.1.1?

Comment: Yes, I switched to "springBootVersion = '1.1.1.RELEASE'" When I use the schema.sql, data.sql, and "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none" then I am back to the unique key violation. If I use "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop" and remove the schema.sql then I get table not found.   I updated my question with a finding about duplicate data.sql being the apparent culprit.  But I dont' know how to resolve that